Is it possible to use topology arguments to find analogies in thermodynamic systems?
I was contemplating whether, given the mathematical structure of thermodynamics, it might be possible to restate some of its most important propositions—or even all of them—purely in topological terms.
The idea is that if we can describe certain relationships between thermodynamic potentials for specific families of systems, we might be able to distinguish these families topologically and thereby prove that some families possess certain properties that others do not.
As an initial step, I considered the possibility of proving that all thermodynamic potentials are homeomorphic under Legendre transforms. This should not be overly challenging, given that we are consistently working with homogeneous functions.
However, these kinds of arguments still seem to require the definition of a metric, as they are fundamentally based on the notion of distance. Specifically, to define a Legendre transform in the classical sense, we need to work within connected open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Perhaps what I am proposing is impossible but my question remains: Has anyone attempted to restate thermodynamic arguments in purely topological terms? If so, did they necessarily have to work within Euclidean space or more generally within metric spaces?

I do not understand why you think that "the need of working within open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$" should imply a metric. In any case, a metric space is always a topological space.

Damn, you are right, I just had by default in mind the existence of a scalar product, but we don't need it in this context. Thanks. However, yes, every metric space is a topological space but my point was "is it possible to do do it without necessarily use a metric space?". I Will think of this more, maybe I'll come to answer my own question eventually

In any case, consider that there is no consensus about the fundamental mathematical structure of Thermodynamics. Some claim that contact structures play an essential role. I prefer to stress the convex cone structure. In both cases, something more than pure topology seems required.

Honestly this is what i think too, and the convex cone structure does seem like a reasonable idea as a basis. Do you mind suggesting some references where I can look for arguments supporting contact structures and/or convex cone structures?

I use the answer here rather than commenting since I (still) don't have enough reputation to add comments.
I assume that Charateodory first and then others, e.g. Truesdell and Noll, have tried a geometrical/topological approach to the undestanding/formalization of the thermodynamics (axioms and consequences).
Unfortunately I am not an expert but generic readings on the subject make me think that the path you suggest may have been tempted yet. Do you know the works of those authors?

I was not aware of their works! I will check them out!
